# YYYYWW format in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, database, function, datetime, amazon-redshift

My company recently migrated to **Redshift from Redash** recently and I'm having a hard time recreating the **YEARWEEK()** function available in MySQL but not in Redshift. I've searched high and low to find a way to do this but can't seem to find the correct resource as I'm also pressed for time.

*table:*   order

*column:*   created_at

*stored as:*   29/03/21 03:02 -- add 8 hours here via date_add()

*desired output:*   **202113** -- yearweek() yyyyww

In MySQL this gives me the correct output YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(o.created_at, INTERVAL 8 HOUR))

Comment: You may use `DATE_PART` with the `w` mask, but I'm not sure that it would correspond 100% to MySQL's `YEARWEEK` function.

Comment: Tried this but it only just gives me the week and not the year with it :< Thanks for the help though Tim. appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if `DATE_PART` accepts more than one part at a time, but in any case, making two separate calls, one for the year and the other for the week, should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `DATE_PART` here along these lines:

```sql
CONCAT(DATE_PART(y, o.created_at + interval '8 hours'),
       DATE_PART(w, o.created_at + interval '8 hours'))
```

Note that it is not clear if the above would produce identical output to MySQL's `YEARWEEK` function.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at + interval '8 hours', 'IYYY-IW');
```

"IW": ISO week number of year (the first Thursday of the new year is in week 1.)

[Redshift Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html)